# take minus(-) sign number from sting and use in in different procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have variable

```
DECLARE @Routs NVARCHAR(1024)
@i int 
SET @Routs = N'6,4,-5,8'
```

I need to extract  any number from this sting, where it have minus sign before it  (-5 in example)
and use it as input parameter with out (-) sing for example @i in different stored procedure.

Comment: Is the string only contains numbers??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty yes its only numbers divided by ',' however number with - can be in any  part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in you're @Routs parameter to a table valued function that will split the list into a table and then loop through the table and if the value is a negative number execute stored procedure or whatever you want or do nothing if its not negative.

--table function to split parameter by comma

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitListOfInts] (@list nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS @tbl TABLE (number int NOT NULL) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @pos        int,
       @nextpos    int,
       @valuelen   int

if len(rtrim(@list)) > 0  
begin

   SELECT @pos = 0, @nextpos = 1

   WHILE @nextpos > 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @nextpos = charindex(',', @list, @pos + 1)
      SELECT @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0
                              THEN @nextpos
                              ELSE len(@list) + 1
                         END - @pos - 1
      INSERT @tbl (number)
         VALUES (convert(int, substring(@list, @pos + 1, @valuelen)))
      SELECT @pos = @nextpos
   END
  end

  RETURN
 END
```

-- stored procedure that calls that split function and uses @routs parameter

```
  CREATE TABLE #values(nbrValue int)
 INSERT INTO #values(nbrValue
 EXEC [dbo].[SplitListOfInts] @routs
```

--if you don't care about non-negatives delete them here

```
 DELETE FROM #values
 where nbrValue >= 0

DECLARE @i int
DECLARE @countrows = (SELECT COUNT(nbrValue) FROM #values)

WHILE @countrows >0
SET @i = (SELECT TOP 1 nbrValue FROM #values)
```

...do what you want

```
DELETE FROM #values where nbrValue=@i
set @countrows = (SELECT COUNT(nbrValue) FROM #values)
END
```

Comment: You should read this article. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings You have created the worst performer for a split function you can come up with. This is a multi statement table valued function with a while loop.

Comment: @BS123 looks like you having interesting solution but i guess i will continue to look

Comment: this function return all numbers but i need only negative numbers i dont care about rest of them

Comment: editted answer to just delete them from temp table and remove the if check to see if it was negative or not.

Comment: @BS123 I did it like this `select * from [SplitListOfINTs](N'2,4,-5,7') where number <0 ` and its return only negative values